# How many subgroups of order 25 in $G = \Bbb{Z}_{360} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{150} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{75} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-product

Let $G = \Bbb{Z}_{360} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{150} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{75} \oplus \Bbb{Z}_{3}$

a. How many elments of order 5 in $G$

b. How many elments of order 25 in $G$

c. How many elments of order 35 in $G$

d. How many subgroups of order 25 in $G$

I think I have done a,b,c correctly and got 124 elments of order 5, 3000 elements of order 25, and 0 elements from order 35,

But I'm not sure if that is correct, and how to approch d?

Comment: Hint: by the Chinese remainder theorem one has $\def\Z#1{\Bbb Z_{#1}}G\cong\Z5\oplus(\Z{25})^2 \oplus\Z{18}\oplus\Z6\oplus(\Z3)^2$

Answer (score 2):

Using the presentation theorem of finite abelian groups, one can restrict the problem to the $5$-primary part of $G$, which is
$$H=\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_{25}\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}.$$

$H$ has $5\times 25\times 25=3125$ elements. There should be $\color{red}{124}$ elements of order $5$, not $24$.

For the number of subgroup of order $25$, look at the two cases where the said subgroup is isomorphic to ether $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_5$ or $\mathbb Z_{25}$.

Comment: yes you are right, I meant 124, it was a typo,
what is $H$, how can you deduce the problem to $H$

Comment: Since $\mathbb Z_{360}\cong \mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_{72}$, $\mathbb Z_{150}\cong \mathbb Z_{25}\times \mathbb Z_6$, and $\mathbb Z_{75}\cong \mathbb Z_{25}\times \mathbb Z_3$, $$G\cong H\times K,$$ where $K$ has order not divisible by $5$. Therefore $H$ contains all elements of order divisible by $5$ in $G$, so the question reduce to working on $H$

Comment: so I counted 465 groups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5\times \mathbb Z_5$ and125 groups isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_25$ is that correct?

Comment: $465$ looks good. Each group $\mathbb Z_{25}$ contains exactly $20$ elements of order $25$.

Answer (score 0):

What method did you use?

In general the cyclic group of order $n$ has $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ whenever $d | n$. (You have $\phi(n)$ elements of order $n$, any element generates a cyclic subgroup, and summing these up gives you the order of the group.)

Also, if you have two elements of order $m$ and $n$, then the order of their sum (in an abelian group) will be $\text{lcm}(m,n)$.

So in $\mathbb Z_{360}$, $\mathbb Z_{150}$ and $\mathbb Z_{75}$ there are $\phi(5) = 4$ elements of order 5, plus the identity, and any sum of these has order 5: this makes $5^3 - 1$ or 124 elements of order 5.

To approach (d), note that every subgroup of order 25 will either be $\mathbb Z_5 \oplus \mathbb Z_5$ or $\mathbb Z_{25}$. You've found the elements of order 5 and of order 25, so can you use this to deduce the answer? (Warning: all 4 of the non-identity elements in a cyclic group of order 5 will generate the same subgroup!)

Comment: so If I take an element of order 25, and look at the group generated by it, I will get a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_25$ ? so I have 3000 of those?
and if I take two elements of order 5 and look at the group generated by them I will get a subroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5 \oplus \mathbb Z_5$ ? and I have $\binom{31}{2}$ of those? cause I have 124 elements, which gives me 31 different groups of order 5, and I can pick any 2 of them?

Comment: @J I think there are way more elements of order $\;5\;$, since any element of the form $\;(a,b,c,0)\;$ , with *at least* one of $\;a,b,c\;$ an element of order $\;5\;$ has order five. You only took the elements with all of $\;a,b,c\;$ elements of order $\;5\;$ .

Comment: there are 5 elements of order dividing  5 in each of the subgroups $\Bbb{Z}_{360}$ , $\Bbb{Z}_{150}$, $\Bbb{Z}_{75}$, so we have $5\times5\times5 = 125$ elments of order dividing 5, one of them is e, so we have 124 of order 5

Comment: @Joanpemo it's entirely possible that I'm wrong, but I'm afraid I don't agree with you with your specific objection: $5 \cdot (a,b,c,0) = (5a, 5b, 5c, 0)$ so will only be the identity if all three of $a, b, c$ have order 5.

Comment: However, I did miss out the fact that the identity also counts, so yes it should be 5 not 4. @DanielKatzan I disagree with your answer of 3000, but otherwise I agree with what you said. You need to ensure that your two elements of order 5 do not generate the same subgroup, however, so not any pair will work.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt Thank you. Perhaps it is now clearer to you, but all we need to orry about is the three first coordinates in the group, correspondig to the cyclic factors of order divisible by five. For each coordinate you can take 5 elements (the four of order five and the unit zero), so you already have $\;5^3=125\;$ elements, but there's one possibility you have to rule out: all the coordinates zero, as this is the unit element of order one, not five, and thus all in all we have $\;125-=124\;$ elements of order five.